# Opposing meanings of the suffix -gena

Tags: vocabulary, suffixes, word-usage

I recently came across the word "deigena" while reading [c. 2, lectio 4 of Aquinas's *Commentary on the Divine Names of [Pseudo-]Dionysius*](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/cdn01.html). This led me to discover what seems to be a productive suffix from *gigno*: *-gena*. Here is a [list of words (with some false positives) of adjectives ending in this suffix](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=gena&lang=la).

I have a few questions about this word:

- There seem to be two, almost opposite, meanings: X-bearing and X-born. Is this correct?
- How should I use this productive suffix? The examples in the list above seem to compound it with the genitive. Could I, for instance, write "librigena" for "book-bearing"?
- Is there a name for this kind of productive suffix?

Comment: Montigena and mortigena make a lovely pair! I wonder if Latin pedants complained as much as I do about iatrogenic diseases (which obviously has to mean diseases which give rise to doctors).

Comment: @MartinKochanski Complaining about doctors in Latin literature is a true, all-Roman tradition. Just ask [Cato the Elder](https://imperiumromanum.pl/en/curiosities/doctors-did-not-have-best-opinion-in-ancient-rome/).

Answer (score 6):

#### The variants *-gena* and *-genus*

This ending has two forms: *-gena* (inflected as a first-declension masculine/common gender noun, potentially used adjectivally) and *-genus, -gena, -genum* (inflected like a first/second declension adjective).

I believe second declension variants in *-genus,* *-genum* etc. are generally rare in ancient times, and become more frequent in later texts. For example, there are no hits for *indigenu* or *indigeno* in the PHI Latin corpus, but this variant of *indigena* can eventually be found in later sources (the [Lewis and Short entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dindigenus) indicates that *indigenum sermonem* can be found in at least some versions of Apuleius's *Metamorphoses*, although I've also seen editions that give it as "indigenam sermonem"), with apparently the same meaning as *indigena.*

#### The primary meaning seems to be "born"

I think the usual meaning of *-gena* and *-genus* is "born".

The ending I would expect for words meaning "X-bearing" is *-fer* or *-ger.*

Aside from your example of Aquinas's "deigena deitas", which I'm not sure how to interpret, there are the following possible cases of *-genus/-gena* meaning "bearing":

- *[florigenus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dflorigenus)*, per L&S "producing blossoms, blossoming"
- *[puerigenus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpuerigenus)* per L&S "that begets boys"
- *[monstrigenus/monstrigena](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/monstrigena)*  per L&S "monster-bearing" (pointed out in a comment by cmw)
- *[morbigenus](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/morbigenus)*  per DMLBS "disease-bearing, that causes illness" (via Logeion)
- *[nubigenus](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/nubigenus)* "cloud-bearing" per Gaffiot 2016 (via Logeion)
- *[ignigenus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dignigenus)* per L&S "producing fire" (of a donkey whose pack was on fire)
- *[omnigenus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Domnigenus2)* per L&S "all-begetting, all-producing (postclass.)"

I think cmw's comment attributing these kinds of examples to "post-classical misinterpretation" of the meaning of the suffix is the correct explanation.

In the course of Googling this suffix, I actually came across an assertion by Josef Niederle ("[Proposals to add examples of correct usage of Latin compounds to Article 23](https://www.iapt-taxon.org/historic/Congress/IBC_2017/Prop214-216.pdf)", TAXON 65 (2) • April 2016: 415), that the variation in form between common-gender nouns in *-gena* and 1st/2nd-declension adjectives in *-genus, -gena, -genum* has a direct correspondence (in "correct usage") to the difference in meaning between "-born" and "-bearing". However, given the existence of counterexamples of words in *-genus* used with the sense "-born" (which Niederle dismisses as erroneous usages), I'm inclined to disagree: I think that there is only an indirect correlation, in that both the use of the form *-genus* and the sense "-bearing" both appear to become more common post-Classically.

#### Word formation: the linking vowel *-i-*

Since words ending in *-gena/-genus* are compounds, they usually have the format "stem" + "linking vowel *-i-*" + "ending". For example, *montigena* "mountain-born" from *mons, montis* and *terrigena* "earth-born" from *terra, terrae* show that *-i-* is not restricted to occurring in words formed from nouns with genitives in *-ī.* Also, the interfix or linking vowel *-i-* that we find in compounds is a short vowel, while the second-declension genitive ending *-ī* is a long vowel.

Therefore, my conclusion would be that "librigena" is validly formed from *liber* and *-gena,* but would be more likely to mean "book-born" than "book-bearing".

Comment: That list has another: [monstrigena](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=monstrigena&la=la&can=monstrigena0&prior=Martigena), but it's so late that I'd chalk it up to a post-classical misinterpretation (along with Aquinas').

Comment: Cf. the Greek linking vowel -o-, which can also occur after stems from words of the 1st declension, wherein any 1st-declension -a- or -e- disappears.